# Adding custom tab in uCommerce - Extending uCommerce

Tags: c#, jquery, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have added a custom tab in uCommerce and followed all the steps that were mentioned [here](http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.6/extending-ucommerce/save-custom-data-in-the-database.html).

Everything is working fine but the only problem is the new tab is coming with square brackets on each side like this - [Order Line Status History]

Can anyone help me with this problem that how can I remove these brackets and from where they are coming as I haven't added them anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems lige you're missing translation resource for the tabs. Try to take a look here: http://eureka.ucommerce.net/#!/question/1067/Adding-custom-resource-key-for-custom-added-tab